# How to specify number of partitions for different code parts of a structured query?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL flow like:

```
dataFrame
  .join(anotherDataFrame, columns)
  .repartition(partitionColumn)
  .save()
```

In the `join` step I want `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled` to be `true`, because this will speed up the join.

In the `repartition` step, I want `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled` to be `false`, for if it was true, it might change the partitions and the saved result would be formatted in wrong partitions.

How can I change the behavior of `spark.sql.adaptive.enabled` in different steps of a Spark SQL flow?

For example:
When there are only 15 rows and I want to repartition them to 3 partitions, according to one column.
But because *spark.sql.adaptive.enabled* is true, the repartition step won't work at all, it is always 1 partition

Answer (score 1):

> How can I change the behavior of spark.sql.adaptive.enabled in different steps of a Spark SQL flow?

You cannot. The setting is per `SparkSession` and all queries that are bound to one `SparkSession` have all the same value of this and any other property.

Just to be clear(er), there is no notion of *"a step in a flow"*. There are logical operators that all together create a structured query. You could call one or more logical operators *"a step"* and a structured query *"a flow"*, but honestly I've never heard of them before and can be very confusing.

---

In theory though specifying different "settings" per logical operator (*"a step"*) is possible using hints.

In fact, the `Join` logical operator "uses" the broadcast hint to select a broadcast hash join at planning time (it's not the logical operator itself but the execution planning strategy that is responsible for planning a logical query plan).

That would however require a bit of re-writing the Spark SQL engine (the Catalyst Framework).